# Django three-step registration

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Please tell me, I'm doing a 3-step registration, using 3 forms that inherit from ModelForm and view classes that inherit from FormView.  The first two pages were ok.  On the first, I write down the first name, last name, mail and number in the session.  On the second, I confirm the mail using the code.  But there is a problem with the third page.  There should be two fields:

1. Enter password
2. Enter the password again.

And here in the form I don’t know how to make the password validation be from Django (well, that is, checking for length, characters, similarity between the first and second input field, etc.).  Tell me, please, how to do this?  From what class to inherit in the form?

views.py

```
class registration_step3(FormView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm3
    template_name = 'html/log_&_reg/registration_add_password.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('authorization')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'registration_data' not in self.request.session:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('registration_step1'))
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print("Форма прошла валидацию успешно.")
        registration_data = self.request.session.get('registration_data')
        print(registration_data)
        if registration_data:
            user = CustomUser.objects.create(
                first_name=registration_data['first_name'],
                last_name=registration_data['last_name'],
                email=registration_data['email'],
                phone_number=registration_data['phone_number'],
                notification_access=registration_data['notification_access'],

                email_verified=True,
                password=form.cleaned_data['password2'],
            )

            del self.request.session['registration_data']
            self.request.session.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            # Handle the case when registration_data is not found in the session
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("Форма не прошла валидацию.")
        print("Ошибки формы:", form.errors)
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm3(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'main_auth-right-form-input main_auth-right-form-input-cod',
                'placeholder': 'Введите пароль',
                'type': 'password',
            }
        ),
        validators=[validate_password]
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'main_auth-right-form-input main_auth-right-form-input-cod-again',
                'placeholder': 'Введите пароль еще раз',
                'type': 'password',
            }
        ),
        validators=[validate_password]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )
```

The problem here is that validation does not work, that is, when we enter the first password and the second one does not check whether they are the same or not, the register does not look either. in general, it does not pass the built-in validation from Django. Instead, we enter anything in these two fields and it still redirects, although it should not and should indicate errors